# Linux mint: how to add applications to taskbar in second monior

Tags: linux-mint

I use two monitors. I tried to have two similar taskbar on both monitors. But I think this is not possible in linux mint. All the applications appear in one taskbar only. Then I tried to add applications/programs to taskbar from menu and again it is added to one taskbar only. I can not take it to second monitor.

So what I basically need is that,

```
1. Same taskbar on both monitor
or 2. I want to be able to add same application for example, google chrome to both taskbar.
or 3. Whenever I open an application, it should appear in both monitor.
```

Any one solution would be fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your setting is `extended` view. Having multiple taskbar for each workspace/monitor isn't possible, yet, as far as I know.

If you need a shortcut to an app, place the shortcut on the desktop and drag it to the second monitor or just create one there.

It is not possible to run duplicate process simultaneously. If you want to see the same thing on both screen, then you will have to change display setting. `Preference->Display->'Mirror Displays' checked

A better place to ask Mint related questions in the [Linux Mint Forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewforum.php?f=90&sid=3bc44d354d28a15e784d9e2768c7cd1d), Newbie Q's Section.